# Loosing column of data when importing large csv file with read_csv

Tags: r, import, readr

I'm importing a 2.2GB csv file with 24 million rows using read_csv(). One of the columns (vital sign_date_time), a character variable, is not being read and is importing with only NA values.

I've opened the .csv file up in SQLServer and can confirm the data is there in the file. I've broken the large file up into smaller chunks in macOS terminal. When I import the smaller files, again with read_csv(), the data is also present.

I'm using the import dialog box in RStudio to minimize any typing errors. In the data view section of the dialog box, it shows only NA data in the column in question and is trying to import the column as a logical field. I've tried manually changing this to character type and it still reads only NA values.

Here's a screenshot of the dialog box:

[image: screen shot of dialog box]

Any ideas about what might be happening?

Thanks.

Take care,
Jeff

Comment: Do you have the same problem using [data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table) `data.table::fread()` and/or [vroom](https://github.com/r-lib/vroom) `vroom::vroom()`?

Comment: are you getting any warnings after you import the file?

Comment: I haven't tried vroom() but did have the same issue with fread().

Comment: I get a ton of errors (84 million/24 million rows but those are all dealing with a different column that is known to be missing in that many rows).

Comment: @jared_mamrot Thanks for the suggestion!!! `fread` bombed/timed out like `read_csv`, but `vroom` worked like magic.  Amazing that one function works and another one doesn't.  I also thought that `vroom` was supposed to be powering `read_csv` now.

Comment: You're welcome @AlfredoGMarquez. Based on the [source code](https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/blob/master/R/read_delim.R) the read_delim family of functions are now powered by vroom but evidently there are still some bugs if `vroom()` worked on your data and `read_csv()` didn't. If your bug is reproducible it would be good to raise an issue on github to help the maintainers improve the readr package, but it might also just be specific to your system. Either way, glad you got your data loaded :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was bitten by a similar problem recently, so this is a guess based on that experience.

By default, if the 1000 first entries of a column are `NA`, `readr::read_csv` will automatically set all values of this column to `NA`. You can control this by setting the `guess_max` argument. Here is the documentation:

```r
guess_max: Maximum number of records to use for guessing column types.
```

For example,

```r
library(readr)
dat <- read_csv("file.csv", guess_max=100000)
```

Comment: Vincent, you nailed it! That was the problem. The first 399K rows were null. After adjusting the guess_max to 400K it worked like a champ! Thanks!